# Is my schematic of the TPS54240 buck converter correct?

Tags: circuit-design, schematics, buck

I am currently working on a small project, where I have to reduce the voltage from 3 LiIon batteries that are chained together in series to ~3.3V in order to power a microcontroller. At first I was using the MP1584 chip, however a few days before I wanted to order the finished PCB the product was labeled as 'Discontinued'. For this reason I searched for other similar chips and found the TPS54240 chip. After reading [this](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps54240.pdf?ts=1598797988448&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) datasheet I created a schematic. However I'm not completely sure whether or not I did everything right, since this is more or less the first time I created one.

Could anyone be so kind and verify that everything is fine? It would really help me a ton! I would also appreciate tips on how I could improve my schematic.

This is the schematic in question:
[image]

Comment: For 1 unit why bother? Learn by example and test it.  https://www.amazon.com/Icstation-AMS1117-3-3-Voltage-Regulator-4-75V-12V/dp/B01N1I1LXH/ref=sr_1_2_sspa?dchild=1&keywords=3.3v+regulator&qid=1598799725&sr=8-2-spons&psc=1&spLa=ZW5jcnlwdGVkUXVhbGlmaWVyPUEyUTZKQ0VWUlgzQlFZJmVuY3J5cHRlZElkPUEwNDAyODUzMkVXTUFXWDVDRFlaRyZlbmNyeXB0ZWRBZElkPUEwMDI3MzQ1M0JaUzRLT1UyVlM3WiZ3aWRnZXROYW1lPXNwX2F0ZiZhY3Rpb249Y2xpY2tSZWRpcmVjdCZkb05vdExvZ0NsaWNrPXRydWU=

Comment: There is much more to it than the schematic

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 Because I actually have a lot more components on my PCB than just the microcontroller and the buck converter, like a solar charger circuit, multiple voltage sensors in order to monitor cell voltages etc. and I want to have one PCB, because I don't like having a lot of PCBs mashed together. For prototyping thats great, but for a finished project I would like to have one clean PCB.

Comment: No it is not fine. Please compare it with the example in the datasheet and you will surely spot multiple errors.

Comment: @Justme Can you tell me what exactly is wrong with it? I did look at the datasheet, but didn't find any mistakes.

Comment: @Justme I mean, sure, I have a few different values for the resistors and I chose a different diode, but that shouldn't be a problem. Is this what you meant?

Comment: If your ESR,DCR, and layout matches TI’s webench design, OK

Comment: Connections of the BOOT pin, PH pin and the placement of the catch diode are completely wrong if you open the datasheet and look at the schematics side by side. Even the simplified schematic on the first datasheet page can be used to verify it.

Comment: @Justme Oh, you are right. Didn't catch that! Thanks.

Comment: https://e2e.ti.com/cfs-file/__key/communityserver-discussions-components-files/196/OP.png

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 Isn't that connection just used to disable the module? The datasheet says "Float to enable" and since I don't want to disable the module having it floating should be correct I thought.

Comment: Perhaps float uses internal pullup

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 That item on Amazon is an LDO regulator, not a buck converter as its title claims.

Comment: TY @AndrewMorton   Whattaya expect for 2 bucks? An LDO.  (LOL) https://www.amazon.com/JacobsParts-Mini360-Voltage-Converter-Module/dp/B078C7ZS74/ref=sr_1_5?dchild=1&keywords=3.3v+buck&qid=1598802710&sr=8-5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few mistakes.

1. BOOT and PH connections are swapped.
2. The catch diode is on the wrong side of coil.
3. Compensation pin is missing a capacitor. If it is not needed, it is a good precaution to draw it, so you have a place for a capacitor if you need it, so you don't have to manufacture new boards just because you don't have a place for an important capacitor.

Answer (score 2):

The two errors fixed, the compensating capacitor is not needed here. One suggestion is to set the frequency to around 300kHz, there are less losses than at 600kHz (R31 200k> 400k). It works nicely with these values ​​anyway.
[image: Kapcs1]

[image: kapcs2]

Answer (score 0):

- if you put one of these on 4 pins , it becomes more replaceable and it’s adjustable, plus you get spares with a better chance of fewer errors, if this is your first SMPS rodeo.

It might need shielding from high impedance analog lines for EMI reduction with a can. Thermal consideration are due if you intended to draw too .much power

[https://www.amazon.com/JacobsParts-Mini360-Voltage-Converter-Module/dp/B078C7ZS74/ref=sr_1_5?dchild=1&keywords=3.3v+buck&qid=1598802710&sr=8-5](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B078C7ZS74)